LAN PS5 have to un and re plug ethernet cable to restore psn connection constantly
I have a netgear cax80 gateway, Comcast 1.2 gigabit internet, and ps5 pro connected via ethernet. My Playstation no longer connects to Playstation network on load up.  It does still connect to internet though. I have to either run internet test on ps5 or re insert the ethernet cable in order for it to connect correctly. However within a couple hours I need to repeat this. I'll lose my friends list and store access, Even while playing and connected. Thumbnails have loading issues too related to ps store.
It used to work perfectly fine for well over a year, suddenly became a persistent issue
I have tried factory resetting on the router, 2 different PlayStation(s), changing ethernet cables, and port forwarding, my cable connection stats show as good with 0 errors and no correctable, latest firmware. My next step will be to change the coax cable. Other than that I don't know what else to try

From what you describe, this sounds like a software issue on the PS5. plugging/unplugging the cable is just telling the PS5 to reinitialize the software connection to the service. if you are getting Internet while this is going on, then the issue is not with your network hardware. The only exception to that i can see is if you are using UPNP to open ports for PSN to work over. when everything is working what is your NAT type? have you forwarded any ports for your PS5?

When you say you tried different Playstations, what was the outcome? Did BOTH have this problem? Have you reviewed your router or gateway for any filtering you may have enabled? When you list what you've tried, please include the outcome for each thing you tried, otherwise you are lacking information we need to better help you.
